# How do I fix the with of my plot based on the example of an answered question?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My previous question got closed and referred to an already answered question that does help me but I can't get the solution to work in my code. It's mostly down to a knowledge gap. I just don't understand everything in the solution and can't find materials that help me to fix it. So this question is that what's wrong in my code.

My original code is down below. It's a simple code that makes N number of plots based on the amount of different groups in column "AMETIALAGRUPP".

```
DATA <- read_xlsx("T:/Data/TEST_DATA.xlsx")

make_plot <- function(ametialagrupp){
  
  DATA <- DATA %>%
    filter(AMETIALAGRUPP == ametialagrupp,
           HARIDUSTASE_YLD == "Korg") %>%
    mutate(OKR_N = fct_reorder(OKR_N, INIMEST)) %>%
    slice_head(n=5)
  
  
p <-  ggplot(DATA ,aes(y=OKR_N, x=INIMEST, fill=HARIDUSVOTI))+
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity',width = 0.8)+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0071ce","#d30031"),
                      name=" ",
                      labels=c("Erialane","Mitteerialane"))+
    theme_minimal()+
    xlab("Inimest")+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())

  ggsave(p, file=paste("AG_",ametialagrupp,"_4" , ".png", sep=""),path="T:/DATA/AG", height=4, width=6, bg="white", scale=1.2)
}

make_plot("Group_1")

for(i in unique( DATA$AMETIALAGRUPP)) make_plot(i)
```

I got referred to this post: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65439901/define-a-fixed-width-height-to-a-bar-chart-then-set-an-absolute-width-to-bars)

I posted the answer code below also and added comments about what I do not understand

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

fixed_bars <- function(data, var, ncols = 6) { #what is var, is it something i need to change or not?
  ncols   <- ncols + 2 #Where does the ncols =6 come from why 6 and +2?
  data    <- mutate(data, {{var}} := as.factor({{var}}))
  levs    <- length(levels(pull(data, {{var}})))
  extra   <- ncols - levs
  x_range <- range(as.numeric(pull(data, {{var}}))) + c(-0.5, 0.5) * extra 

#Since I don't fully understand ggplot mechanics I don't understand the code

  ggplot(data, aes(x = {{var}})) +
    geom_bar() +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = x_range)
}
```

Now my attempt to integrate the two codes. My plan was to make two functions. One for fixed plot and one for make plot. I can't even get the fixed_plot to work with my data. I hate to make posts that are fix my code but i'm just stumped by it. :(

```
DATA <- read_xlsx("T:/Data/TEST_DATA.xlsx")

fixed_bars <- function(DATA
, var, ncols = 6) {
  ncols   <- ncols + 2
  data    <- mutate(AMETIALAGRUPID, {{var}} := as.factor({{var}}))
  levs    <- length(levels(pull(AMETIALAGRUPID, {{var}})))
  extra   <- ncols - levs
  x_range <- range(as.numeric(pull(AMETIALAGRUPID, {{var}}))) + c(-0.5, 0.5) * extra
  
  ggplot(AMETIALAGRUPID, aes(y = {{var}} x=INIMEST, fill=HARIDUSVOTI)) +
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0071ce","#d30031"),
                      name=" ",
                      labels=c("Erialane","Mitteerialane"))+
    theme_minimal()+
    xlab("Inimest")+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom",
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = x_range)
}

mpg %>%
  fixed_bars(OKR_N)
 

make_plot <- function(ametialagrupp){
  
  DATA <- DATA %>%
    filter(AMETIALAGRUPP == ametialagrupp,
           HARIDUSTASE_YLD == "Korg") %>%
    mutate(OKR_N = fct_reorder(OKR_N, INIMEST)) %>%
    slice_head(n=5)
  
  
p <-  DATA >%>
     fixed_bars(OKR_N)

  ggsave(p, file=paste("AG_",ametialagrupp,"_4" , ".png", sep=""),path="T:/DATA/AG", height=4, width=6, bg="white", scale=1.2)
}

make_plot("Group_1")

for(i in unique( DATA$AMETIALAGRUPP)) make_plot(i)
```

Comment: Hi Picataro. I have closed this as a duplicate, as there is a working solution to your problem in the linked post. If you are struggling to apply this to your own situation, please let us know where you get stuck. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I did not find the post when I was looking around. I will give it a go now. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AllanCameron Can you please help me with integrating your previous answer to my code. I can't get it to work. Thank you

Comment: Test Data link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rVynyxkJWqOqx83WsT2N8YKXPme2cSO-?usp=sharing